# Visual Studio ignores UseDebugLibraries from .props

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019, vcxproj, vsprops

I have the following .props file, generated with CMake (but this does not seem to be a CMake problem):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <UseDebugLibraries>true</UseDebugLibraries>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
        <UseDebugLibraries>false</UseDebugLibraries>
    </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

I have another .props file, next to this one in the .vcxproj, but it is correctly merged when i open it in Visual Studio, they look like this in the project file:

```
<ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
  <Import Project="other_props_file_that_works.props;does_not_work.props" Condition="exists('other_props_file_that_works.props;does_not_work.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
</ImportGroup>
```

Not really relevant, but the props are added like this in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
set_property(TARGET "${PROJECT_NAME}" PROPERTY VS_USER_PROPS ${USE_DEBUG_LIBARIES_PROPS_FILE_PATH} APPEND)
```